# Annular regions in which the Laurent series converges

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

For the series $$\sum^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{z^n}{3^n + 1}$$
Determine the annular region in which this series converges.

I understand that $\sum^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{z^n}{3^n + 1}$ can be split into $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{z^n}{3^n + 1} + \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{z^{-n}}{3^{-n} + 1}$

We have defined the upper boundary of convergence as $R^{-1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mid C_n \mid ^{1/n}$ and the lower as $L = \lim_{m\to\infty} \mid C_{-m} \mid ^{1/m}$ (which is the negative powers of z)

But I can't understand how to calculate $R^{-1}$ ($\lim_{n\to\infty} \mid \frac{1}{3^{n} + 1} \mid $) in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to look at this.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{3^n+1}
$$
converges for $\left|z\right|\lt3$.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{z^n}{3^n+1}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac1z\right)^n}{3^{-n}+1}
\end{align}
$$
converges for $\left|\frac1z\right|\lt1$

Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^n}{3^n+1}
$$
converges for $1\lt\left|z\right|\lt3$.